# How to add items as values in a dictionary with no values?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of keys with empty value pairs like this:

```
dict = {a : "" , b : "" , c : "" , d : "" , e : "" , f : ""}
```

I have a list of pairs

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7...]
```

How do I add the nums as values in the dictionary so it looks like this:

```
dict = {a : 1, b : 2, c : 3...}
```

Comment: You can't have a dictionary with no values.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you get more specific with your question? Can you print and show an example for the dictionary that you have? For example, is the dictionary of the form dict_ = {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c':None}? Also, do you have a specific match in mind? Like do you require that key 'a' is matched with 1, key 'b' matched with 2, and so on, or you can match the numbers to any of the dictionary keys?

Comment: Please provide a code example of the dictionary you have - this is not valid Python: `dict = {a : , b : , c : , d : , e : , f : ,}`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
r =  {'a' : '', 'b' : '', 'c' : '', 'd' : '', 'e' : '',' f' : '',}  
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 

dict(zip(r.keys(),nums))  
#{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, ' f': 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean sth. like that?

```
keys = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
dct = {key: value for key, value in zip(keys, nums)}
print(dct)
```

By all means, do not call your variables like builtins (e.g. `dict`, `list`, ...).

Comment: You don't need a dict comprehension there. You can simply do `dict(zip(...))`.

Comment: @Selcuk: It is essentially the same as `dct = dict(zip(keys, nums))` - `zip` returns an iterator which needs to be consumed either way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to fill the values of the dict with value from the array. I think the below example would help you:

```py
a = {'a' : "", 'b' : "", 'c' : "", 'd' : "", 'e' : "", 'f' : "",}
values = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
final_dict = dict()

for key in a.keys():
    final_dict.update({key: values.pop(0)})

print(final_dict)
#{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 3, 'e': 4, 'd': 5, 'f': 6}
```

Comment: Note that this will only work in Python 3.7 or later as dictionaries are not ordered in earlier versions.